# How to hide the 'Quit' Button on Jupyter Notebook server?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook server where other people have access to and I'd like to hide the 'Quit' button:
[image: 'Quit' button] from all users in order to avoid server shutdown by accident.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `c.NotebookApp.quit_button` option in your `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file. The line to add is:

```
c.NotebookApp.quit_button = False
```

If you don't already have this file, create a new one by running:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

If you create the sample config file using that command, you should already see a commented-out version of the `quit_button` option. Uncomment it and set it to false.